# socket http request is failing

Tags: c, sockets, http, ubuntu

I am writing simple c program to send http request, to a USB modem device which is loaded(cdc_ether) is having 192.168.0.144 ip address with ethx interface up on ubuntu machine.I am able to send request successfully http request is failing. Since device is controlled with http requests for control management.

define BUFFSIZE 512

```
define MAXBUF 512

void error(char *msg);

int serverSocket;

int i,n = 0;

size_t bWritten, bTotal;

struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;

struct hostent *hostptr;

const int optVal = 1;

const socklen_t optLen = sizeof(optVal);

char buffer[BUFFSIZE];

char *set_cmd_post="/goform/goform_set_cmd_process";

char *host="192.168.0.1";

char sendline[BUFFSIZE + 1]={0};

char recvline[BUFFSIZE + 1]={0};

char *post_str_connect="goformId=CONNECT_NETWORK\r\n";


int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int j=0;

    memset(&serverAddr, 0, sizeof(serverAddr));
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(80);
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.0.1");


    snprintf(sendline, MAXBUF,
             "POST %s HTTP/1.1\r\n"  // POST or GET, both tested and works. Both HTTP 1.0 HTTP 1.1 works, but sometimes
             "Host: %s\r\n"     // but sometimes HTTP 1.0 works better in localhost type
             "Connection: Keep-alive\r\n\r\n"
             "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
             "Content-length: %d\r\n\r\n"
             "%s", set_cmd_post, host, (unsigned int)strlen(post_str_connect), post_str_connect);
    serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (serverSocket < 0)
        error("socket()");
    int rtn = setsockopt(serverSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (void*) &optVal, optLen);

    if (connect(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr)) < 0)
        error("connect()");

    printf("connect to server success \n");

    if (send(serverSocket, sendline, strlen(sendline),0)>= 0)
    {
        printf("write success \n");

        do
        {

            n = recv(serverSocket, recvline, sizeof(recvline), 0);
            if (n > 0 )
                printf("%s", recvline);
        }
        while ( n > 0 );

    }

}
```

output:

POST /goform/goform_set_cmd_process HTTP/1.0

User-Agent: rndis_socket

Host: 192.168.0.1

Accept: */*

Content-length: 24

Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

goformId=CONNECT_NETWORK

HTTP/1.0 200 OK

Server: GoAhead-Webs

Pragma: no-cache

Cache-control: no-cache

Content-Type: text/html

{"result":"failure"}

Answer (score 0):

yes its working now some line endings missing figured it out using wireshark.

snprintf(sendline, MAXBUF,

"POST %s HTTP/1.1\r\n"

"User-Agent: %s\r\n"

```
"Host: %s\r\n"
```

"Accept: */*\r\n"

```
"Content-length: %d\r\n"
```

"Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n\r\n"

"%s", set_cmd_post,agent,host, (unsigned int)strlen(post_str_connect), post_str_connect)

char *post_str_connect="goformId=CONNECT_NETWORK";

Thanks